# Как в контроллере получить не зашифрованный пароль авторизованного пользователя?

Tags: symfony, symfony3

Как в контроллере получить не зашифрованный пароль авторизованного пользователя?

На странице документации есть пример:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_password_authenticator.html

Как мне передать вот это значение `$token->getCredentials()` в контроллер?

Использую *Symfony 3.4*

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller.html#the-request-object-as-a-controller-argument) написано, как использовать `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` в контроллере. Самописный аутентификатор для этого не нужен.

Подставляем в методе тайпхинт, и симфони сама инжектит

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
//...
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
}
```

Достаём из запроса параметры:

```
$username = $request->request->get('username');
$password = $request->request->get('password');
```

Свойство `request` - это тело POST/PUT/PATCH запроса в виде ассоциативного массива.

Если же вы пытаетесь узнать пароль пользователя, сделавшего запрос и не передавшего с этим запросом пароля - вы неправильно спроектировали своё приложение. Не нужно хранить реальные пароли пользователей.